# ListView not updating on drag and drop

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, drag-and-drop, uwp

I have two ListViews which I'm trying to setup drag and drop functionality on. Each ListView is data bound to an ObservableCollection (_upcomingList and _inProgressList), where Tasks is one of my models.

The way I have it set up, when the DragItemsStarting method is called, the Id of the item being dragged (from the ListView bound to _upcomingList) is stored in a string and set as the DataPackage. Then, when the item is dropped in the second ListView (bound to _inProgressList), the id is extracted from the DataPackage and I use it to search for the complete entry in my db. Finally, the item's status is changed to 'In Progress' and added to _inProgressList.

When I run the app and attempt to drag an item from one ListView to the next, nothing happens on screen, however, the `await UpdateTask(taskToMove)` definitely runs properly, because I can see the Tasks table get updated in the database and the next time I run the app, the task that I attempted to drag over to the In Progress ListView now appears there. Here is the implementation of my drop method (there's a newer version below in the update section):

```
public async Task IPLV_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text))
    {
        var id = await e.DataView.GetTextAsync();
        var tasksToMove = id.Split(',');

        tasks = await taskTable.ToCollectionAsync();

        if (_inProgressList != null)
        {
            foreach (var taskId in tasksToMove)
            {
                var taskToMove = tasks.First(i => i.Id.ToString() == taskId);

                taskToMove.Status = "In Progress";

                _inProgressList.Add(taskToMove);
                _upcomingList.Remove(taskToMove);

                await UpdateTask(taskToMove);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything appears to run properly so I've missed a step somewhere along the line to have the app recognize when list items are added and removed from an ObservableCollection or to have the ListViews their bound to update when their source has changed.

Thanks in advance to anyone who reads this!

**UPDATE**

I recently found a Drag and Drop example on Shen Chauhan's blog (http://www.shenchauhan.com/) which caused me to change my Drop method a bit. Now instead of attempting to add the dropped item to my ObservableCollection directly, I create a new collection populated with the itemsource of the ListView and add the dropped item to that.

The updated Drop method has solved the issue of dropped items not appearing in the InProgress ListView, however, I'm still having trouble getting the dropped item to be removed from the Upcoming ListView. Here's my complete implementation as it currently exists:

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    MainPageViewModel vm = new MainPageViewModel();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UpcomingListView_DragItemsStarting(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
    {
        var tasks = string.Join(",", e.Items.Cast<Tasks>().Select(t => t.Id));
        e.Data.SetText(tasks);
        e.Data.RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Move;
    }

    private void inProgressListView_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.AcceptedOperation = (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text)) ? DataPackageOperation.Move : DataPackageOperation.None;
    }

    private async void InProgressListView_Drop(object sender, DragEventsArgs e)
    {
        await vm.IPLV_Drop(sender, e);
    }
}
```

**MainPageViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private MobileServiceCollection<Tasks, Tasks> tasks;
    private IMobileServiceSyncTable<Tasks> taskTable = App.MobileService.GetSyncTable<Tasks>();

    private ObservableCollection<Tasks> upcomingList = default(ObservableCollection<Tasks>);
    public ObservableCollection<Tasks> _upcomingList { get { return upcomingList; } set { Set(ref upcomingList, value); } }

    private ObservableCollection<Tasks> inProgressList = default(ObservableCollection<Tasks>);
    public ObservableCollection<Tasks> _inProgressList { get { return inProgressList; } set { Set(ref inProgressList, value); } }

     ...

     public async Task IPLV_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
     {
         var id = await e.DataView.GetTextAsync();
         var tasksToMove = id.Split(',');

         var inProgressListView = sender as ListView;
         var IPLVItemsSource = inProgressListView?.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<Tasks>;

         tasks = await taskTable.ToCollectionAsync();

         foreach (var taskId in taskToMove)
         {
             var taskToMove = tasks.First(t => t.Id.ToString() == taskId);

             _upcomingList.Remove(taskToMove) // DOES NOT REMOVE ITEM

             taskToMove.Status = "In Progress";

             IPLVItemsSource.Add(taskToMove); // NOW WORKS

             await UpdateTask(taskToMove); 
         }             
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your sample? It's difficult to reproduce your problem depending on your posted code.

Comment: Hi @GraceFeng-MSFT. Thanks for commenting. I've posted more code as well as a small update as half of my problem has been resolved to some extent. Please let me know if anything sticks out to you or if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to figure it out as I mentioned in my comment to @GraceFeng-MSFT. For anyone else who might have this issue, here's what my final solution ended up looking like which included some minor tweaks to `InProgressListView_Drop()` in **MainPAge.xaml.cs** and `IPLV_Drop()` in **MainPageViewModel.cs**:

```
private async void InProgressListView_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    ObservableCollection<Tasks> sourceListView = upcomingListView?.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<Tasks>;

    await vm.IPLV_Drop(sourceListView, sender, e);
}
```

---

```
public async Task IPLV_Drop(ObservableCollection<Tasks> source, object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var id = await e.DataView.GetTextAsync();
    var tasksToMove = id.Split(',');

    var inProgressListView = sender as ListView;
    var IPLVItemsSource = inProgressListView?.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<Tasks>;

    ObservableCollection<Tasks> test = source; // TODO: Change var name

    if (IPLVItemsSource != null)
    {
        foreach (var taskId in tasksToMove)
        {
            var taskToMove = test.First(I => i.Id.ToString() == taskId);

            source.Remove(taskToMove);

            taskToMove.Status = "In Progress";
            IPLVItemsSource.Add(taskToMove);

            await UpdateTask(taskToMove);
            await RefreshTasks();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In `IPLV_Drop` task, you have a `tasksToMove` and a `taskToMove` (I can't see where you define this in your posted code), and you traversed the `taskID` in `taskToMove` and then in the `tasks` collection find the first one which matched the `taskID`.

Your `_inProgressList` and `_upcomingList` are `ObservableCollection<Tasks>`, when you operate on these two collections, the item's data model should be `<Tasks>`. Now you get a item from `MobileServiceCollection<Tasks, Tasks> tasks`, but you used `tasks = await taskTable.ToCollectionAsync();` first, so the item's data model changed, but it should be a `Collection`, it's not `<Tasks>`.

> When I run the app and attempt to drag an item from one ListView to the next, nothing happens on screen, however, the await UpdateTask(taskToMove) definitely runs properly, because I can see the Tasks table get updated in the database and the next time I run the app,...

So I think the item found inside the `foreach (var taskId in taskToMove)` can only be used for your database operation, if you want to refresh the UI, you need probably code like this:

```
public async Task IPLV_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var id = await e.DataView.GetTextAsync();
    var tasksToMove = id.Split(',');
    foreach(var taskToMove in tasksToMove)
    {
        __inProgressList.Add(taskToMove);
        _upcomingList.Remove(taskToMove);
    }


    //var inProgressListView = sender as ListView;
    //var IPLVItemsSource = inProgressListView?.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<DataModel>;

    tasks = await taskTable.ToCollectionAsync();

    foreach (var taskId in taskToMove)
    {
        var taskToMove = tasks.First(t => t.Id.ToString() == taskId);

        //_upcomingList.Remove(taskToMove) // DOES NOT REMOVE ITEM

        taskToMove.Status = "In Progress";

        //IPLVItemsSource.Add(taskToMove); // NOW WORKS

        await UpdateTask(taskToMove); //this used for update database?
    }
}
```

Since I can't reproduce your issue using your code snippets, if you have any problems here, please leave a comment.

Comment: Hi @GraceFeng-MSFT, thanks for this post. I can't use taskToMove to add or remove to either of my ObservableCollections because it's just a string containing the Id--not an entire Tasks entry. However when you said "```tasks = await taskTable.ToCollectionAsync(); first, so the item's data model changed...```" you got me thinking. The problem I was having related to the call to my MobileService with `taskTable.ToCollectionAsync();` I'll post the full solution below but removing that call solved my problem. Thanks again for all of your help!

Comment: @wrigley06, OK, is that possible that using the string type "taskToMove in tasksToMove" to find the comparable item in your `_inProgressList` and `__inProgressList`, like the code you used to find items in `MobileServiceCollection`, just find the item in `ObservableCollection` then add/delete it.

Comment: I suppose another way to go about it would be to iterate through _upcomingList and then write `if (_upcomingList[j].Id == taskId) { _upcomingList.RemoveAt(j); _inProgressList.Add(taskToMove); }` Is that along the lines of what you were thinking? If so, do you think that would have a positive impact on performance?

Comment: @wrigley06, I thought your `Task IPLV_Drop` is in `MainPageViewModel` and so are the `ObservableCollection<Tasks>`s, you can directly operate these two collections. Now you get the sender as `ListView`, and then get `ListView`'s `ItemSource`  as  `ObservableCollection<Tasks>`, it's actually the same as `_inProgressList`, it's just round a circle to come back...